# How to create an ical duration field in Django?

Tags: django, datetime, field, icalendar, rfc5545

I use a Django model that I register with the admin site. One of the fields of my model represents a duration. I would like to use the DateTimeField, but instead of saving the value to a datetime in the database, I would like to save it as varchar, formatted according to RFC5545 (ical) (e.g., a duration of 1 day 1 hour 1 min 1 sec would be stored as "P1DT1H1M1S"). How would I do this? Should I overwrite the DateTimeField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom Django field for it instead of overwriting DateTimeField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just subclass `model.Field.` And define two methods:

**[Field.to_python(self, value)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python)** - will convert db value to python object.

**[Field.get_prep_value(self, value)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value)**  - this is opposite to `to_python` converts object to db value.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for (I meant subclassing instead of overwriting...). Actually, I was not subclassing DateTimeField, as a duration is a bit different. Instead, I created my own field (see answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bakkal and Pol. Below is what I came up with.

```
from django.db import models
from icalendar.prop import vDuration
from django.forms.widgets import MultiWidget
from django.forms import TextInput, IntegerField
from django.forms.util import flatatt
from django.forms.fields import MultiValueField
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.text import capfirst
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core import validators
from datetime import timedelta

def is_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

class Widget_LabelInputField(TextInput):
    """
    Input widget with label
    """
    input_type="numbers"
    def __init__(self, labelCaption, attrs=None):
        self.labelCaption = labelCaption
    super(Widget_LabelInputField, self).__init__(attrs)

    def _format_value(self, value):
        if is_int(value):
            return value
        return '0'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = '0'
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
        if value != '':
            # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
            final_attrs['value'] = force_unicode(self._format_value(value))
        if (self.labelCaption):
        typeString = self.labelCaption + ': '
        else:
            typeString = ''           
        return mark_safe(u'' + typeString + '<input%s style=\'width: 30px; margin-right: 20px\'/>' % flatatt(final_attrs))



class Widget_DurationField(MultiWidget):
    """
    A Widget that splits duration input into two <input type="text"> boxes.
    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (Widget_LabelInputField(labelCaption='days', attrs=attrs),
                   Widget_LabelInputField(labelCaption='hours', attrs=attrs),
                   Widget_LabelInputField(labelCaption='minutes', attrs=attrs),
                   Widget_LabelInputField(labelCaption='seconds', attrs=attrs)
                   )
        super(Widget_DurationField, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            duration = vDuration.from_ical(value)
            return [str(duration.days), str(duration.seconds // 3600), str(duration.seconds % 3600 // 60), str(duration.seconds % 60)]
        return [None, None, None, None]



class Forms_DurationField(MultiValueField):
    widget = Widget_DurationField
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_day': _(u'Enter a valid day.'),
        'invalid_hour': _(u'Enter a valid hour.'),
        'invalid_minute': _(u'Enter a valid minute.'),
        'invalid_second': _(u'Enter a valid second.')
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        errors = self.default_error_messages.copy()
        if 'error_messages' in kwargs:
            errors.update(kwargs['error_messages'])
        fields = (
            IntegerField(min_value=-9999, max_value=9999,
                      error_messages={'invalid': errors['invalid_day']},),
            IntegerField(min_value=-9999, max_value=9999,
                      error_messages={'invalid': errors['invalid_hour']},),
            IntegerField(min_value=-9999, max_value=9999,
                      error_messages={'invalid': errors['invalid_minute']},),
            IntegerField(min_value=-9999, max_value=9999,
                      error_messages={'invalid': errors['invalid_second']},),
        )
        super(Forms_DurationField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
            if data_list[0] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_day'])
            if data_list[1] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_hour'])
            if data_list[2] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_minute'])
            if data_list[3] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_second'])

            return vDuration(timedelta(days=data_list[0],hours=data_list[1],minutes=data_list[2],seconds=data_list[3]))
        return None




class Model_DurationField(models.Field):
    description = "Duration"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model_DurationField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'varchar(255)'

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "Model_DurationField"

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, vDuration) or value is None:
            return value

        return vDuration.from_ical(value) 

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return value.to_ical() 

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': Forms_DurationField,
            'required': not self.blank,
            'label': capfirst(self.verbose_name),
            'help_text': self.help_text}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(Model_DurationField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Comment: as an apology, I am a python/Django beginner, so probably the code is not very efficient or clean... ;-) Any ways to improve it are appreciated!

Comment: Dude, nont post you questions as answer. Community will not appreciate it. Instead, crate new question, or update the current one.  And dont forget to accept an appropriate answer.

Comment: okay, I am new to stackoverflow. I will create a new question and accept an answer, as you suggest. thanks,

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635320/object-has-no-attribute-in-custom-django-model-field

Comment: I was stupid. The problem was that I named the file where the model was defined duration.py, so there was a naming conflict with the "duration" field. I renamed the file and it worked.